# How to parse this json object?

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, parsing

this is the JSON object and I need to access the **gps-recs**: entries.  The dash (-) is giving me and error on not defined when I tried to parse:

```
"recs-count": 139, 
"gps-recs": [
    { 
        "RecId": 40020551513, 
        "City": "New Port Richey", 
        "Country": "USA", 
        "County": "PASCO", 
        "State": "FL", 
        "Street": "1546 Amaryllis ct.", 
        "ZipCode": "34655", 
        "CurrentOdometer": 12161, 
        "Heading": 0, 
        "Latitude": 28.181690, 
        "Longitude": -82.658420, 
        "SpeedMph": 0, 
        "SpeedLimitMph": 25, 
        "Status": "Stopped", 
        "StatusDuration": "1.05:00:00", 
        "PrimaryLandmarkName": "Max's home", 
        "CurrentHardmountEvent": null, 
        "UtcTimeTag": "2013-11-28T05:23:34", 
        "UserTimeTag": "2013-11-28T00:23:34", 
        "UserInfo": { 
            "UserId": 201274, 
            "UserNumber": "22", 
            "UserName": "Max's Car" 
        } 
    },
    { 
        "RecId": 40020551610, 
        "City": "New Port Richey", 
        "Country": "USA", 
        "County": "PASCO", 
        "State": "FL", 
        "Street": "1546 Amaryllis ct.", 
        "ZipCode": "34655", 
        "CurrentOdometer": 12161, 
        "Heading": 0, 
        "Latitude": 28.181690, 
        "Longitude": -82.658410,
```

This is my code:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'URL',
   };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  var result = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(result);
    console.log(Object.keys(result).length);
    });
```

the parse statement I am trying to use to parse the portion inside the gps-recs entry is:

```
var result = JSON.parse(body).gps-recs;
```

I am receiving the following error message:
ReferenceError: recs is not defined

Comment: Can you post the error message that's being given?

Comment: `JSON.parse` is throwing an error? Or what is? Where / how are you trying to access the values?

Comment: when I tried to parse var result = JSON.parse(body).gps-recs.  The error says: ReferenceError: recs is not defined.

Comment: Try `var result = JSON.parse(body)['gps-recs']`

Comment: `JSON.parse(body).gps-recs` means `JSON.parse(body).gps - recs` i.e. subtract the value of `recs` from the value of `JSON.parse(body).gps`.

Comment: @dan08 It worked perfectly.  Thank you very much!

Comment: To all that replied thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access like this  `data["gps-recs"]`

You should update your code like below:

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  var result = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(result["gps-recs"]);
  console.log(result["gps-recs"].length);
});
```